# NodeJs: Error: Cannot find module 'util/types'

Tags: node.js

How can I fix this error? I am new to NodeJs && don't even know where to begin :-(

I created an empty directory, opened it with VS Code and installed two packages, then tried a very basic unit test. VS Code does not report any problems.

```
npm install --save-dev chai
npm install --save-dev sinon
```

then

```
PS G:\personal\NodeJs\sandbox> npm run tests
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59941/e90fd36f-1d95-419c-a34e-719a52a7c7e6
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.

> unit_testing_wth_mocha_chai_and_sinon@1.0.0 tests
> mocha

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53847/7f4b2c6a-9e9a-4c5a-9842-08943fe8b975
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.

Error: Cannot find module 'util/types'
Require stack:
- G:\personal\NodeJs\sandbox\test\tests.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\personal\NodeJs\sandbox\test\tests.js:4:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:169:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)
    at async formattedImport (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:7:14)
    at async Object.exports.requireOrImport (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:48:32)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:103:20)
    at async singleRun (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async Object.exports.handler (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:374:5)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
PS G:\personal\NodeJs\sandbox>
```